# Close all angular bootstrap accordions in an ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I have a situation where there are a series of ngb-accordions created in an ngFor loop, one created for each item in the data that is labeled an accordion:

```
       <span *ngFor="let item of menu.items">
        <!-- accordion menus -->
        <ngb-accordion
          #pageAccordion="ngbAccordion"
          *ngIf="item.url === '#accordion'" //in the json, says this item is an accordion
          [activeIds]="activePanel"
          [destroyOnHide]="false"
        >
```

The component has a viewchild for this accordion:

```
  @ViewChild('pageAccordion', { static: false })
  pageAccordion: NgbAccordion;
```

And I want to collapse all accordions:

```
    this.pageAccordion.collapseAll();
```

The problem is it only collapses **the first one** created in the ngFor loop.  None of the other ones close.

How can I target or loop through all the dynamically created accordions and call their `collapseAll` method?

I am using Angular 8 and Angular Bootstrap 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You has severals ng-accordion, so use ViewChildren. (ViewChild only get the first ng-accordion)

```
@ViewChildren('pageAccordion') pageAccordions:QueryList<NgbAccordion>
//you can use also
//@ViewChildren(NgbAccordion) pageAccordions:QueryList<NgbAccordion>


//a function to close all the accordions
closeAll()
{
   this.pageAccordions.forEach(acc => {
      acc.collapseAll()
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy your answers helps me a lot.